# How to show a sum of positive definite operators is still positive definite?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, hilbert-space

Consider a Hamiltonian $H$ of the form
$$\begin{split}H&=\sum_{i,j}A_{ij}^\dagger A_{ij},\\ 
A_{ij}&=(1-\sigma_i^z\sigma_j^z)e^{-g (\sigma_i^x+\sigma_j^x)},\end{split}$$
where $g\in\mathbb{R}$ is a real parameter and $\sigma_i^x$ and $\sigma_i^z$ are the Pauli matrices $x$ and $z$ acting on the $i$th spin (qubit). Obviously, each term $A_{ij}^\dagger A_{ij}$ in the summation is positive definite. What I found in numerics is that the eigenvalues of $H$ are all non-negative. How should I prove (or disprove) that $H$ is positive definite?

I am aware that supersymmetric quantum mechanics Hamiltonians are positive definite. Can the above Hamiltonian be cast into a supersymmetric form explicitly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three remarks. One, a sum of positive (semi)definite matrices is again positive (semi)definite. The proof is really easy. Let's work over the reals for simplicity. A matrix $H_I$ is positive definite iff for any vector $v$, we have
$$v^T \cdot H_I \cdot v > 0\,.$$
Now let $H = \sum_I H_I$ be a sum of a finite number of positive matrices $H_I$. Then for any vector $v$, we have
$$v^T \cdot H \cdot v = \sum_I v^T \cdot H_I \cdot v > 0$$
because a sum over positive numbers is again positive.

Two, the operator $A_{ij}$ is only *semi*definite, because it annihilates certain states. Consider for instance the two-qubit state
$$ | \psi_{ij} \rangle = | + \rangle_i \otimes | + \rangle_j - | - \rangle_i \otimes | - \rangle_j\,.$$
Then I think that $A_{ij} | \psi_{ij} \rangle = 0$ (unless I made a mistake). To check this you first show that
$$\exp\left[-g( \sigma_i^x + \sigma_j^x)\right]$$
leaves $|\psi_{ij} \rangle$ invariant, and second that it's killed by $1 - \sigma_i^z \sigma_j^z$.

Third, you want to cast the Hamiltonian into a form $H = Q^\dagger Q$, right? In linear algebra this is known as a Cholesky decomposition. Since $H$ is positive semidefinite, it's certain that such a $Q$ exists (and that it's upper triangular), but it will not be unique in general. There are standard algorithms to compute (at least one realization of) $Q$ if $H$ is a concrete matrix.

Comment: Thanks. I was stupid to ask the question without much thinking.

Comment: It seems to me that your comment on supersymmetric quantum mechanics is not right. First, for a Hamiltonian to be (N=2) supersymmetric, it must take the form $H= Q Q^\dagger +Q^\dagger Q$. Second, the operator $Q$ should be nilpotent of degree 2: $Q^2=0$, which does not hold for a generic lower triangular matrix Q. Indeed, it would be very surprising if any Hamiltonian would be supersymmetric!